# Discontinuity of fractional part function through epsilon-delta form.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was trying to find the discontinuity in the fractional part function of x using the epsilon-delta (precise definition)form and I ended up with no answer.
Though it is obvious from the graph of the fractional part function that it is discontinuous at integers but I found it pretty abstruse when I tried to prove the same through the epsilon-delta form.
My attempt 
we know that 
$$ f(x) ={x}=
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x$ $\notin$ integer} \\
3n+1, & \text{if $x$ is $\in$ integer}
\end{cases}$$

Now if we apply the definition of continuity at any integral point $c$, then we can write 
$$|f(c+h)-f(c)|< \epsilon $$
$$\Rightarrow |h|<\epsilon$$

and since we needed to prove that $$|c+h-c|< \delta$$
We have actually proven the result for continuity which is actually completely false since the fractional part function is not continuous at integral points.
Can anybody please help me out with a detailed proof so as to help me get through the epsilon-delta definition of continuity and limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m \neq 0$ be an integer. Then there is some $\varepsilon > 0$, say $\varepsilon := |m|/2$, such that for every $|m| > \delta > 0$ there is some $x$, say $x := m + \frac{\delta}{2}$, such that $|x-m| < \delta$ and $|x-\lfloor x \rfloor - m + \lfloor m \rfloor| \geq \varepsilon.$ For, note that 
$$
|x - \lfloor x \rfloor - m + \lfloor m \rfloor | \geq ||x-m| - |\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor m \rfloor || = ||x-m| - |m|| = |m| - \frac{\delta}{2} \geq \frac{|m|}{2} = \varepsilon.
$$

Suppose $m=0$. Then there is some $\varepsilon > 0$, say $\varepsilon := \frac{1}{2}$, such that for every $0 < \delta < \frac{1}{2}$ there is some $x$, say $x := \frac{-\delta}{2}$, such that $|x| < \delta$ and $|x - \lfloor x \rfloor| = |x+1| \geq 1- \frac{\delta}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2} = \varepsilon.$

Comment: Sorry just found that I typed only the proof for $m \neq 0$. Here I attached a proof for $m=0$ for completeness. But you may already worked it out :).